# Nasty SQL query: is there a way I can find first and last rows in a grouped set without a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I have data that looks like this:

[image: data sample]

What I need to do is, for records having the same `ClientId`, I need to group consecutive rows (using CpId) where `PlaceId` is not null, and find the first and last row in each group so that I can retrieve the `DateAdmitted` value from the first row and the `DateDischarged` value from the last row.  So, the above data needs to be organized like this and then filtered for the values I need:

[image]

Using the above example, I would want the following based on `ClientId`:

```
ClientId    FirstCpIdInSet    DateAdmitted    LastCpIdInSet    DateDischarged
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1967        NULL              NULL            NULL             NULL
1983        45                1986-12-29      45               1987-10-09
1983        47                1990-10-01      49               2009-04-12
1983        52                2009-08-31      52               2009-11-30
1988        62                1997-12-15      65               2000-01-07
```

`ClientId` 1967 could be excluded from the result set, since it never has a row where `PlaceId` is not null.  A couple of other things to note:

- This is taken from a temp table that is created with `CpId` as the `IDENTITY`, and the table is populated with a strict `ORDER BY`, so `CpId` is sequential in the order needed.
- For those rows that have `PlaceId` and are consecutive for a single `ClientId`, the `DateAdmitted` should equal the `DateDischarged` in the previous row.

I'd really like to be able to do this without a cursor, if possible, but after puzzling on it for two days I just can't figure it out.  This is on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Can you further clarify?  What does "consecutive for a single ClientID" mean?  Is this in terms of CPID?

Comment: Sorry, seems as though I wasn't clear.  Yes, it is somewhat in terms of CpId, but it also needs to be grouped by client, and NOT by PlaceId, but rather by records that HAVE a PlaceId for that client and are consecutive.  I will attempt to edit and clarify.

Comment: Hopefully a picture speaks a thousand more words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you are basing first and last on.  Let me assume it is CPID.  You can do this with ranking functions:

```
select ClientID, PlaceId,
       max(CpID) as max(CPId),
       min(case when seqnumasc = 1 then DateAdmitted end) as DateAdmitted,
       max(case when seqnumdesc = 1 then DateDischarged end) as DateDischarged
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by clientID, placeID order by cpid) as seqnumasc
             row_number() over (partition by clientID, placeID order by cpid desc) as seqnumdesc
      from t
     ) t
where placeID is not null
group by ClientID, placeID
```

This puts in sequence nubmers to determine the first and last rows in each group.  However, why can't you just use min and max on date addmited and discharged?

Based on enhanced information . . .

Now the question appears to be to define the "sets" of records according to the following conditions:

- Consecutive CPIDs
- Same client, same company
- Place not null

If so, the following will give you a "set id".  This uses a trick for bringing together consecutive values, based on subtracting a sequential number from the CPID.  This difference is a constant for consecutive values, providing a set id.

```
select clientid, setid,
       min(DateAdmitted) as DateAdmitted,
       max(DateDischarged) as DateDischarged,
       min(cpid) as minCPID,
       max(cpid) as maxCPID
from (select clientid, setid, cpid,
             row_number() over (partition by clientid, setid order by cpid) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by clientid, setid) as setsize
      from (select t.*,
                   (cpid - row_number() over (partition by clientid order by cpid)
                   ) as setid
            from t
            where PlaceID is not NULL
           ) t
    ) t
group by clientid, setid
```

Comment: I can't use min and max on the dates because it's possible that a client could be admitted and discharged multiple times NOT in succession.  In those cases, I have to make sure that I get the admitted and discharged dates for ALL consecutive sets.  I'm trying your solution now, thank you.

Comment: Edited original question to clarify the "first" and "last," thanks.

Comment: Please see the picture I added, hopefully that will clarify.

Comment: This will not work.  I can't partition on PlaceId, as it will be different between consecutive rows in the set.

Comment: Are you determining the groups by CPID or by date?

Comment: As in the second image that I added to the OP, the groups are segmented per ClientId AND consecutive CPIDs where PlaceId is not null.

Comment: I gave up and used a cursor.  I think ROW_NUMBER over PARTITION would have worked in a situation where I could qualify the partition better.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Nasty query indeed.  Like most SQL problems it comes down tackling different aspects of the problem in the correct order.  My solution doesn't use cursors.  It does use outer apply and partition by.

Realization:
row_number() over (partition by xx order by yy) by itself won't work, because, yy is typically spanning multiple xx partitions.

Example Data:

```
id  state
1   a
2   a
3   b
4   c
```

desired ranges:

```
1 <= x < 3
3 <= x < 4
4 <= x
```

Step 1 - Use an Outer Apply to find the next state transition for every row.  This allows you to check each row's next value based on any criteria you want.  This step likely generates more information than you want.  Several rows could transition to the same value. In this example id 1 and 2 transition at id 3.

pseudo code:

```
select t1.id, t1.state, t3.id, t3.state
from table1 t1
outer apply
(
  select 
    --only grab one row
    top 1 t2.id, t2.state
  from table1 t2 
  where 
    --grab a value that's generated after the current value.
    t1.id < t2.id 
    -- add whatever join logic you need for your case.
    and t1.memberid=t2.memberid 
    -- make sure you get the correct order, typically an identity or time
    order by t2.id asc
) T3
```

This query generates something like this:

```
id  state id    state
1   a     3     b
2   a     3     b
3   b     4     c
4   c     null  null
```

We don't want the row with id = 2.

Step 2 - Partitioning by the transition column allows you to get a row number value that will always be 1 when a state transition occurs.  Just filter by 1 and you have your state transitions.

initial results:

```
row_number  id  state   id  state
1           1   a       3   b
2           2   a       3   b
1           3   b       4   c
1           4   c      null null
```

filtered results:

```
row_number  id  state   id  state
1           1   a       3   b
1           3   b       4   c
1           4   c      null null
```